# why Android Studio does not allow me to create a new package/class under different falvors?

Tags: android, android-studio

**I am using Android Studio 2.2 preview 3 .** 
I am creating free/paid flavors.  Facing issue like - 
1. not able to create java package/class in paid flavor.
2. different color symbols like blue in free not in paid.

**I searched & tried all the solutions given on web. please help.**

Comment: Please upload a screenshot of your project tree, and your build.gradle file

Comment: got solution - changing the build varients from free to paid from below left, allowing to do that. thanks.

Comment: @orelzion. since i am new member of stack overflow, I dont have enough reputation to attach image. BTW Thank you so much.